# LLDB – Set watchpoint on instance variable of arbitrary object

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb, watchpoint

For some weird reason, seguieing back to a view controller changes the `userInteractionEnabled` of my view's subview `_settingsButton` which is of `UIButton` type. I want to know why this happens. After setting a breakpoint in the view controller's code, I attempt to do this:

[image]

But I have no idea how to access an instance variable of the `_settingsButton` property of my view controller. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the simplest way to do this is to set a symbolic breakpoint on (in your case) `[UIButton setUserInteractionEnabled:]`, in the breakpoints panel on the left side.  Click +, then symbolic breakpoint, and then the quoted string above.  I have done this in the past and it does work, so if you have any grief with the above, you could fiddle with the syntax a bit.

Comment: Right, the point here being that properties are really data, and so aren't something you can watch.  There is sometimes a backing ivar - and if you happen to know what it's name is you can watch that.  But there may not even be that, just a getter that returns the value, and a setter that sets it...  Note also, it is possible to rename the setters & getter's, so they won't necessarily have the canonical name.  That's just something to keep in mind if the breakpoint you put on the setter isn't being hit.